# EnableScanInQuery no longer works for new CosmosDB containers

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am getting confused with cosmos-db indexing policy and implicit full-scans.

My end goal is:

- prevent accidental full-scans on non-indexed properties
- index only explicitly specified properties

Lets say I have a table like this one:

```
{
  "id": "transactions",
  "indexingPolicy": {
    "indexingMode": "consistent",
    "automatic": true,
    "includedPaths": [
      {
        "path": "/transactionId/?"
      },
      {
        "path": "/createdOn/?"
      }
    ],
    "excludedPaths": [
      {
        "path": "/*"
      },
      {
        "path": "/\"_etag\"/?"
      }
    ]
  },
  "partitionKey": {
    "paths": [
      "/chargePointId"
    ],
    "kind": "Hash"
  }
}
```

I presume it means I have exactly 2 consistent indexes (on transactionId and on createdOn columns). Azure portal does not allow me to specify index types: it "accepts" the change, but when it reloads the page all changes are gone.

Now I execute a query on a non-existing column with disabled full-scan, assuming it will fail with an error: `An invalid query has been specified with filters against path(s) excluded from indexing. Consider adding allow scan header in the request.`.

But, it does not happen. It works fine and prints `00:00:00` in console.

```
var policy = new ConnectionPolicy()
{
    ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Gateway
};

var client = new DocumentClient(host, key, policy);

var queryText = "select * from c where c.asdasdasd > '2'";

var query = client.CreateDocumentQuery(
     UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("transactions", "transactions"),
     queryText,
     new FeedOptions
     {
         PopulateQueryMetrics = true,
         EnableScanInQuery = false,
         EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true,
     }
).AsDocumentQuery();

var result = await query.ExecuteNextAsync();
var metrics = result.QueryMetrics;

Console.WriteLine(metrics.Single().Value.QueryEngineTimes.IndexLookupTime);
```

(code is taken from this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-query-metrics)

The table I am talking about is created recently (~ few weeks ago). I also have a table in another database-account created ages ago. If I try to do the same trick on that table - it fails as I expect.

I did not find any differences in account or table arm-templates (exported from azure portal).

Why does not it fail on the new table?
Does it still silently index things or `EnableScanInQuery` is no longer respected for new tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am from the CosmosDB Engineering Team. We are gradually removing support for EnableScanInQuery since it was not uniformly enforced for every possible query (SELECT * from r, for example). Besides, partial scans were still allowed when EnableScanInQuery is set to false (even if one of the least selective predicates in a query satisfy large numbers of documents and can be served from the index, we would accept the query, even though it could effectively be a scan). For new containers starting early this year, support is gradually being removed. The recommended way to optimize queries to avoid scans is to examine query execution metrics to determine if any optimizations need to be made with respect to index policy.

What this effectively means is that regardless of EnableScanInQuery, the query might degrade to scan automatically to serve results, and the user will not see any error message for containers that do not support this option.